# How compare two string without considering spaces and case of string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have this code:

```
public class TestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Vijay Kakade";
        String b = "vij";

        if (a.contains(b)) {
            System.out.println("11");
        } else {
            System.out.println("22");
        }
    }
}
```

This example should return 11 but it returns 22.

Comment: Vijay Kakade contains vij so you are getting output

Comment: Sorry, but this example DOES NOT return 11. It returns 22.

Comment: I know this example not return 11 .I have 22 output.So for that what method i have to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) to remove spaces, and use [`toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) to bring both strings to the same case, then use [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if (a.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().contains(b.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()))
```

---

To make this null safe (defining `null` as not equal to anything, not even another null):

```
if (a != null && b != null && a.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().contains(b.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()))
```

Or, if null is considered "equal" to another null:

```
if (!((a == null) ^ (b == null)) || a != null && a.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().contains(b.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: The above is not nullSafe. I have implemented this using a utility method that checks for nulls...


`public static boolean caseAndWhiteSpaceInsensitiveEq(String a, String b){
        a = (null != a) ? a.replaceAll("\\s+","").toUpperCase() : null;
        b = (null != b) ? b.replaceAll("\\s+","").toUpperCase() : null;
        if(null == a && null == b){
            return true;
        }
        if(null == a || null == b){
            return false;
        }

        return a.equals(b);
    }`

Not sure how to make the above formatted nicely :(

Comment: @chad see edited answer for two null safe impls with (I believe to be) a minimum of code

Answer (score 11):

You can replace spaces and use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (a.replace(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(b.replace(" ", ""))) {
```

If you want to also disregard other whitespace characters you can use `replaceAll`:

```
if (a.replaceAll("\\s", "").equalsIgnoreCase(b.replaceAll("\\s", ""))) {
```

---

If you want instead to check for *containment*, use [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [`toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29):

```
if (a.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().contains(b.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase())) {
```

Again, if you want to disregard other whitespace character use `replaceAll("\\s", "")` as shown above.

Comment: I use replace but this can not give me the specified output..it give me 22 ..means not matched..

Comment: @vijayk Yes, the strings in your example are not equal even if we ignore spaces and ignore case. What do you mean by "match"?

Comment: @vijayk the outputs shouldn't match, because "vijaykakade" isn't the same as "vij".

Comment: I would prefer the use of the [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) function to ignore spaces.

Comment: @Vdolez `trim()` only removes spaces at the beginning and end, not spaces in the middle of strings, so this won't work if you want to disregard all spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
     String a = "V    i     jay Kakade";
        String b = "vI  j";
        if (a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "").trim().contains(b.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""))) {
            System.out.println("11");
        } else {
            System.out.println("22");
        }
```

Comment: what if String b = "vij a y";

Comment: you need toLowerCase() for both Strings (?)

Comment: its a validate for another string is that the string is not contains spaces

Comment: Sorry for first post, I forgot to consider that 2nd string could have space and Cases. Taken care in latest post/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Set both `a` and `b` to lowercase and remove spaces, then make your comparison:

```
    String a = " V I J a y Kakade";
    String b = " V i j ";

    a = a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");
    b = b.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");

    if (a.contains(b)) {
        System.out.println("11");
    } else {
        System.out.println("22");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

String a = " V I J a y Kakade";
    String b = " V i j ";

```
a = a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");
b = b.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");

if (a.contains(b)) {
    System.out.println("11");
} else {
    System.out.println("22");
}
```